# Inactivate but show option in multiple select

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have this multiple select , and as you can see , the first option and his name it´s **SELECT YOUR OPTION**

```
<select name="services" multiple="" class="s_select">
<option>SELECT YOUR OPTION</option>
<option>Option 1</option>
<option>Option 2</option>
<option>Option 3</option>
<option>Option 4</option>
<option>Option 5</option>
</select>
```

The problem it´s all people can select all options and also select this not value option called **"SELECT YOUR OPTION"** , yes it´s possible deactivate , etc , but i want continue to show this option , but that the people can´t select

**My question it´s** , how i can show "SELECT YOUR OPTION" value , and don´t let people select never , but also continue to show , i can´t find never in HTML code for do this , and i don´t know if using jquery it´s possible

I hope understand my question , thank´s for the help , regards

Comment: you miss a value for each option. Just add a blank value to the first option and when you submit the form check that the select has a value that is not blank before submitting

Comment: Use this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/n0dg6dso/#&togetherjs=2o9OnKtCbx)

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways you could do this.

**Option Disabled**

*This will show the option, but now allow it to be clicked*

```
<select name="services" multiple="" class="s_select">
   <option disabled>SELECT YOUR OPTION</option>
   <option>Option 1</option>
   <option>Option 2</option>
   <option>Option 3</option>
   <option>Option 4</option>
   <option>Option 5</option>
</select>
```

**OptGroup**

*You can put your first item as a group label to let it look like a heading and not selectable.*

```
<select name="services" multiple="" class="s_select">
  <optgroup label="SELECT YOUR OPTION">
   <option>Option 1</option>
   <option>Option 2</option>
   <option>Option 3</option>
   <option>Option 4</option>
   <option>Option 5</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vq56vtj5/1/

Comment: Ah nice perfect :)